# ionic framework datetimepicker without jquery-bootstrap dependencies

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I am developing a mobile app using ionic framework. I am looking for a datetime picker without jQuery and bootstrap dependencies. As ionic is using Angular its better if there is any angular datetimepicker without bootstrap.
I found this angular-datepicker https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker but this is no longer maintained.

Comment: Why not use HTML5 datetime-local input type ? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_datetime-local

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/

Comment: @TechMa9iac HTML5 datetime-local input displays the default datetime in the android which is not desirable

Comment: @cfprabhu ngcordova- datePicker only support date for android. I need date time both.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this component: https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker

Demo: http://codepen.io/katemihalikova/full/dYvjzP/

Usage:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ion-datetime-picker ng-model="datetimeValue">
    {{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss"}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the followings controls:

for Datepicker
https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

for timepicker
https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker

Comment: Though your links may answer the question, it's recommended that you answer the question here itself as links might tend to change or break.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it resolved,

```
<ion-list>
  <span class="item" ion-datetime-picker ng-model="datetimeValue" >
    {{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"}}
   </span>
</ion-list>
```

Unfortunately Andrey Shatilov I dint get a popup with date and time when I tried with  ion-item inside ion- list

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But fortunately

```
<ion-list>
    <span class>
     </span>
</ion-list>
```

this code saved me.

This is how my [Date Time picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58PaI.png) looks like